# three.js - update (copy?) object position

Tags: javascript, three.js

I just instantiated an object for every vertex of another mesh, and applied some morph targets to this last one. Unfortunately, when I tweak the shape of the big mesh, the instantiated little meshes do not move at all! They stand still like the english queen's guards.
My question is: is there any way to let the little ones *follow* the other one's vertices? Keep in mind I'm using a `for` loop with an array where I push `object2.clone()`s for every vertex.

Thanks in advance!

UPDATE: Here's a portion of the code i'm using:

```
// some stuff before
var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
// SFERETTE
var sfera = new THREE.SphereGeometry(1.5, 24, 20, 0, Math.PI * 2, 0, Math.PI * 2);
var material2 = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial( {
    color: 0x005c6c
} );

var mesh2 = new THREE.Mesh( sfera, material2 );

// ARRAY POSIZIONAMENTO VERTICI
var sferetta = mesh2.clone();
sferetta.matrixWorldNeedsUpdate = true;
sferetta.position.needsUpdate = true;
//  sferetta.matrixAutoUpdate = false;

var vertexArray = [];
for (var i = 0; i < geometry.vertices.length; i++) {
    vertexArray.push(geometry.vertices[i])
}
for (var i = 0; i < vertexArray.length; i++) {
    sferetta.position.set(vertexArray[i].x, vertexArray[i].y, vertexArray[i].z)

    mesh.add(sferetta.clone())
}
// TUTTA LA GIOSTRA SM

scene.add( mesh );

// MORPHING
var params = {
    influence1: 0,
    influence2: 0,
    influence3: 0,
    influence4: 0,
    influence5: 0,
    influence6: 0,
    influence7: 0,
    influence8: 0,
    influence9: 0,
    influence10: 0,
    influence11: 0,
    influence12: 0,
    influence13: 0,
    influence14: 0,
    influence15: 0,
    influence16: 0
};
var gui = new dat.GUI();
var folder = gui.addFolder( 'Morph Targets' );
folder.add( params, 'influence1', 0, 1 ).step( 0.01 ).onChange( function( value ) { mesh.morphTargetInfluences[ 0 ] = value; } );
folder.add( params, 'influence2', 0, 1 ).step( 0.01 ).onChange( function( value ) { mesh.morphTargetInfluences[ 1 ] = value; } );
folder.add( params, 'influence3', 0, 1 ).step( 0.01 ).onChange( function( value ) { mesh.morphTargetInfluences[ 2 ] = value; } );
folder.add( params, 'influence4', 0, 1 ).step( 0.01 ).onChange( function( value ) { mesh.morphTargetInfluences[ 3 ] = value; } );
folder.add( params, 'influence5', 0, 1 ).step( 0.01 ).onChange( function( value ) { mesh.morphTargetInfluences[ 4 ] = value; } );
folder.add( params, 'influence6', 0, 1 ).step( 0.01 ).onChange( function( value ) { mesh.morphTargetInfluences[ 5 ] = value; } );
folder.add( params, 'influence7', 0, 1 ).step( 0.01 ).onChange( function( value ) { mesh.morphTargetInfluences[ 6 ] = value; } );
folder.add( params, 'influence8', 0, 1 ).step( 0.01 ).onChange( function( value ) { mesh.morphTargetInfluences[ 7 ] = value; } );
folder.add( params, 'influence9', 0, 1 ).step( 0.01 ).onChange( function( value ) { mesh.morphTargetInfluences[ 8 ] = value; } );
folder.add( params, 'influence10', 0, 1 ).step( 0.01 ).onChange( function( value ) { mesh.morphTargetInfluences[ 9 ] = value; } );
folder.add( params, 'influence11', 0, 1 ).step( 0.01 ).onChange( function( value ) { mesh.morphTargetInfluences[ 10 ] = value; } );
folder.add( params, 'influence12', 0, 1 ).step( 0.01 ).onChange( function( value ) { mesh.morphTargetInfluences[ 11 ] = value; } );
folder.add( params, 'influence13', 0, 1 ).step( 0.01 ).onChange( function( value ) { mesh.morphTargetInfluences[ 12 ] = value; } );
folder.add( params, 'influence14', 0, 1 ).step( 0.01 ).onChange( function( value ) { mesh.morphTargetInfluences[ 13 ] = value; } );
folder.add( params, 'influence15', 0, 1 ).step( 0.01 ).onChange( function( value ) { mesh.morphTargetInfluences[ 14 ] = value; } );
folder.add( params, 'influence16', 0, 1 ).step( 0.01 ).onChange( function( value ) { mesh.morphTargetInfluences[ 15 ] = value; } );
folder.open();
```

Comment: add the objects as children of the larger mesh.. note that their positions are relative to their parent's center. good luck

Comment: Are you using `THREE.Geometry` or `THREE.BufferGeometry`?

Comment: You either need to interpolate the morph targets with javascript, or do something like render to texture, and then read those positions on the gpu.

Comment: also some code wouldnt hurt

Comment: I'm actually using THREE.Geometry, how can i post a portion of my code?